# Помогите! Нужно проверить: является ли цифры в числе неповторимыми, если да, то вывести это число. c#

Tags: c#, математика

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        int tempNum = 0;

        if (Sort(number, tempNum) == true)
            Console.WriteLine($"программа выполнена успешно, ваше число: {number}");
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число повторяется, введите разные цифры.");
        }
    }

    static bool Sort(string number, int tempNum)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<number.Length; i++)
        { 
            if (number[i] != number[tempNum])
            {   
                tempNum = number[i];
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вот мой код, я решил делать это через массив. Не знаю верно ли выбрал путь, но выводит ошибку *System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."*

Comment: добавь пример как вызываешь, какое число вводишь.

Comment: `if (number.ToSting().Disinct().Count() == number.ToSting().Length)`. P.S.: [что такое .Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Я исправил ошибку, но теперь я не могу понять, как разделить массив посимвольно используя Split() - разрешает только через пробел

Comment: зачем что то делить посимвольно? Строка уже сама представляет собой массив символов

Comment: Что-то [вроде такого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NftBri) у вас должно быть, где число это число, а не строка, где идет с ним "математика" тег которого вы поставили, ну и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string enteredString = Console.ReadLine();
        //Проверяем что ввели числовое значение
        var isNumeric = int.TryParse(enteredString , out int n);
        if (!isNumeric)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Введено неверное значение. Введите число.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (UniqueCharactersInAString(enteredString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Программа выполнена успешно, ваше число: {enteredString}");
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Цифры в введённом числе повторяются, введите разные цифры.");
            }
        }
    }    
    //Проверяет уникальность каждого символа в строке(что символ не дублируется)
    static bool UniqueCharactersInAString(string originalString)
    {
        foreach (char ch in originalString)
        { 
            if (originalString.Count(c => c == ch) > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант, использующий только "простые" средства в виде циклов и метода [`Char.IsDigit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-7.0):

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(OnlyUniqueDigits(number) 
            ? $"программа выполнена успешно, ваше число: {number}"
            : "Неправильный ввод, введите разные цифры."
        );
    }

    static bool OnlyUniqueDigits(string number)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = number.Length; i < n - 1; i++)
        { 
            if (!Char.IsDigit(number[i])) {   // найден нецифровой символ
                return false;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (number[i] == number[j]) { // найден дубликат
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```